# Parsing a text file in Python

Tags: python

I am new in python and I am trying to extract values out of a text file. 
Input:

```
Vlan101, Interface status: protocol-up/link-up/admin-up, iod: 257,
  IP address: 1.1.1.1, IP subnet: 1.1.1.0/24
  IP broadcast address: 255.255.255.255
```

Output:

```
Vlan101,1.1.1.0/24
```

I have a code which is working but not giving me the desired output.

My code:

```
 if 'Vlan' in text:
            vlanArray = text.split(",")
            print(vlanArray[0])
        if 'IP subnet' in text:
            ipAddress = text.split(":")
            lenipAdd = len(ipAddress)
            print(ipAddress[lenipAdd-1].strip())
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question and format your code properly using the `{}` button. Use the preview to get sure it looks right.

Comment: What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: Looks like your code is in a loop that reads line by line. Split on `": "`, not `":"`, and print `ipAddress[-1]`. Ain't Python great?

Comment: You want to get output from input?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you going a bit to fast. I would suggest to first try an intermediate step:

```
vlanArray = text.split(",") 
for txt in vlanArray:
    print(txt)
```

This should give you direction about the next steps to take.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for 2 or more split of same text. Try below:

1. Do the split of the text and store in an array
2. Run the loop through the array
3. Check if the array item contains Vlan or IP subnet
4. If true, append in the output variable

Like below:

```
   vlanArray = text.split(",")
   outTxt = []
   for subTxt in vlanArray:
      if 'Vlan' in subTxt:
          outTxt.append(subTxt)

      if 'IP subnet' in subTxt:
          ipAddress = subTxt.split(":")
          lenipAdd = len(ipAddress)
          outTxt.append(ipAddress[lenipAdd-1].strip())

    outTxt = ','.join(outTxt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to extract the information you need:

```
s = """Vlan101, Interface status: protocol-up/link-up/admin-up, iod: 257,
  IP address: 1.1.1.1, IP subnet: 1.1.1.0/24
  IP broadcast address: 255.255.255.255"""


import re
m = re.match(r'^([\d\w]+)(.*)(IP subnet: )([0-9./]+)', s, re.DOTALL | re.S | re.MULTILINE )
result = m.groups()

print (result[0], result[-1])
```

Returns:

```
Vlan101 1.1.1.0/24
```